# Visualforce with jQuery and HTML Files Separately

Tags: visualforce, jquery, html

Have a question if it is possible to have a visualforce page that is referencing both an .htm document and a jquery (.js) file that are loaded as static resources. The logic behind it is to keep the `<script>` section to a minimum on the VF page by making a large function on the .js static resource and likewise to keep all of the `<div>`s that are being referenced on the separate .htm file. Is this possible/better way to accomplish? Thanks as always you guys are great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

George ,I am not sure of using static resource for view part .One thing i have been using to keep VF clean is using apex:include tag that allows me to include a VF inside another VF .I will keep this for view and may be another VF just to host the script .The JS script can also be used in components and components imported to VF can help you final VF clean.